# Cancel RACCommand execution

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reactive-cocoa, raccommand

Is there any way to cancel execution of a `RACCommand`?

For example I have a command with infinite execution signal like this:

```
RACCommand *command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        __block BOOL stop = NO;

        while (!stop) {
            [subscriber sendNext:nil];
        }

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            stop = YES;
        }];
    }];
}];
```

So how can I stop it after calling `[command execute:nil]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit new to RACCommand, so I'm not certain there's a better way to do this. But I have been using `takeUntil:` with a cancellation signal to halt execution.

```
RACCommand *command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        while (true) {
            [subscriber sendNext:nil];
        }
    }] takeUntil:cancellationSignal];
}];
```

Comment: Great, thanks! There is some more info here https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1326